# What is meaning of size in json file for drag and drop collapsible tree in d3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

I want to use d3.js drag and drop collapsible tree. The example has flare.json file where name and size are mentioned like:
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [{
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "size": 3938
            }, {
                "name": "CommunityStructure",
                "size": 3812

What is the meaning of size here and how to calculate. If I don't use size in the json file then the look and feel of the tree is different than in the example.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: What's the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Flare was a predecessor to D3. The size refers filesize as is not used in the collapsible tree. It is used in [this example](http://deliveryimages.acm.org/10.1145/1750000/1743567/figs/f4e.jpg) (sorry could only find an image).